# Regex match text followed by curly brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text like this:

```
"entity"
{
    "id" "5040044"
    "classname" "weapon_defibrillator_spawn"
    "angles" "0 0 0"
    "body" "0"
    "disableshadows" "0"
    "skin" "0"
    "solid" "6"
    "spawnflags" "3"
    "origin" "449.47 5797.25 2856"
    editor
    {
        "color" "0 0 200"
        "visgroupshown" "1"
        "visgroupautoshown" "1"
        "logicalpos" "[-13268 14500]"
    }
}
```

What would regex expression be to select only that part in Notepad++:

```
editor
{
    "color" "0 0 200"
    "visgroupshown" "1"
    "visgroupautoshown" "1"
    "logicalpos" "[-13268 14500]"
}
```

First word is always "editor", but the number of lines and content in curly brackets may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editor\s*{\s*(?:\"[a-z]*\"\s*\".*\"\s*)*\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qHjGm9/1/)
Also tested it in Notepad++ it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find everything between curly brackets would be `\{[^{}]*\}` ([example 1](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/1)).

You can prepend `editor\s*` on it so it limits the search to only that specific entry: `editor\s*\{[^{}]*\}` ([example 2](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/2)).

However... if any of the keys or value strings within `editor {...}` contain a `{` or `}`, you're going to have [edge cases](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/3).

You'll need to find double-quoted values and essentially ignore them. [This example](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/4) shows how you would stop before the first double quote within the group, and [this example](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/5) shows how to match up through the first key-value pair.

You essentially want to repeatedly match those key-value pairs until [no more remain](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/6).

If your keys or values can contain `\"` within them, such as `"help" "this is \"quoted\" text"`, you need to look for that `\` character [as well](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/7).

If there are nested groups within this group, you'll need to recursively handle those. Most regex (Notepad++ included) don't handle recursion, though, so to get around this, you copy-paste what you have so far inside of the code if it happens to come across [more nested](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/8) `{` and `}`. This does not handle more than [one level](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/9) of nesting, though.

**TL;DR**

For Notepad++, this is [a single line regex](https://regex101.com/r/FelKjC/10) you could use.